# Operations on state of array

Tags: react-native

I am developing an application on ReactNative, which works over `geoquery`. Simply, I am getting data with the help of `geoquery` then showing in `FlatList`.

But the problem is that I am using an state of array as,

```
this.state = {
       data: []    
}
```

How to add the `keys` I am getting from `geoquery` in this state of array.

I am using `geoquery` as,

```
geoQuery.on('key_entered', (key, location, distance) => {
            console.log(key + " entered query at " + location + " (" + distance + " km from center)");
        })
```

I want to add `key` getting from geoquery to an state of array, then get data of related key from firebase with the help of state of array containing `key`.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the geoquery data?

Comment: Added an example. @WilliamPark

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding from your question, you can do something like below:

```
geoQuery.on('key_entered', (key, location, distance) => {
        console.log(key + " entered query at " + location + " (" + distance + " km from center)");
        this.setState({data: [...this.sate.data, key]});
    })
```